# Basic toolbar crashes app

Tags: java, android, xml, toolbar

I created a basic tool bar off the android website and it is crashing with a code it gives to put in the onCreate Section. the only widget in the program so far is that and it crashed with the .java code

home.java

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Home extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    Toolbar my_toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(my_toolbar);
}
}
```

xml

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
```

Comment: what error message do you get?

Comment: gradle sync failure and  session app error launching activity

Comment: Can you share error log?

Comment: Provide your logcat.

Comment: Is your `Home` activity defines in `AndroidManifest`

Comment: 01-03 03:00:05.338 3167-4386/? E/QMI_FW: QCCI qmi_cci_xport_recv: txn not found. svc_id: 16
01-03 03:00:05.338 3167-4385/? E/LocSvc_LBSApiV02: E/virtual int lbs_core::LBSApiV02::injectCoarsePosition(const CoarsePositionInfo &):352]: Error : st = 3, ind.status = 0
01-03 03:00:05.338 3167-5118/? E/LocSvc_libulp: E/int ulp_brain_transition_all_providers(), no QUIPC/GNSS transition logic run due to both engines are OFF 

these came up as errors in it but it gets longer as i try to copy

Comment: yes it id defined

Comment: clean your project and rebuild it

Comment: still crashed after a clean and rebuild

Comment: if i remove the code in .java it works fine but how can i avoid that

Comment: @EquiWare What you mean if i remove the code in .java..

Comment: if i take out the 2 lines of code regarding the toolbar it will run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the theme of your activity `Home` does not have an `ActionBar` already. Check the manifest file to find out which theme is being used.

Also check the file `styles.xml` and make sure the the theme used by your activity does not have an `ActionBar`. Use something like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Comment: The toolbar that you saw earlier was a default `ActionBar.` You haven't placed the `Toolbar` properly in your xml file. Edit the question and post the full xml file of your activity.

Answer (score 0):

In your styles.xml put below code..

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

and in your AndroidManifest.xml write the theme as below

```
       <activity android:name=".Home"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
```